# PHP Array to List

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-lists, unordered

How do I go from this multidimensional array:

```
Array (
  [Camden Town] => Array (
    [0] => La Dominican
    [1] => A Lounge
  ), 
  [Coastal] => Array (
    [0] => Royal Hotel
  ), 
  [Como] => Array (
    [0] => Casa Producto 
    [1] => Casa Wow
  ), 
  [Florence] => Array (
    [0] => Florenciana Hotel
  )
)
```

to this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Camden Town</li>
  <ul>
    <li>La Dominican</li>
    <li>A Lounge</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Coastal</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Royal Hotel</li>
  </ul>
  ...
</ul>
```

above is in html...

Comment: so many things. This is my last gasp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a much more maintainable way to do it than to echo html...

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $array as $city => $hotels ): ?>
    <li><?= $city ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach( $hotels as $hotel ): ?>
            <li><?= $hotel ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Here's another way using h2s for the cities and not nested lists

```
<?php foreach( $array as $city => $hotels ): ?>
<h2><?= $city ?></h2>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $hotels as $hotel ): ?>
        <li><?= $hotel ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The outputted html isn't in the prettiest format but you can fix that. It's all about whether you want pretty html or easier to read code. I'm all for easier to read code =)

Comment: this is the correct answer. Perfect. 
Thanks for introducing me to endforeach. this is EXACTLY what I have been looking for.

Comment: @Ash you may note, that `endforeach` is used here for the sense of readability, so the ordinary `foreach` can be used. See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 24):

```
//code by acmol
function array2ul($array) {
    $out = "<ul>";
    foreach($array as $key => $elem){
        if(!is_array($elem)){
                $out .= "<li><span>$key:[$elem]</span></li>";
        }
        else $out .= "<li><span>$key</span>".array2ul($elem)."</li>";
    }
    $out .= "</ul>";
    return $out; 
}
```

I think you are looking for this.

Comment: Rockstar code right here.  Thanks for saving me the time of building it!

Comment: I love that it's recursive

Answer (score 9):

Refactored acmol's funciton

```
/**
 * Converts a multi-level array to UL list.
 */
function array2ul($array) {
  $output = '<ul>';
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $function = is_array($value) ? __FUNCTION__ : 'htmlspecialchars';
    $output .= '<li><b>' . $key . ':</b> <i>' . $function($value) . '</i></li>';
  }
  return $output . '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data is in $array.

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($array as $city => $hotels)
{
    echo "<li>$city</li>\n<ul>\n";
    foreach ($hotels as $hotel)
    {
        echo "    <li>$hotel</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n\n";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure it's right.

Comment: This isn't quite what was requested, but it is probably what was intended.  Some CSS will complete the formatting.

Comment: actually the above code only provides one "child" for each parent, so for example  Camden Town is only given one hotel listed instead of 2.

Comment: its recommended to use echo over print in PHP